# Older Clients & Wallets

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core

I have about 5 BTC stored in Wallets created under different versions of Bitcoin, all encrypted with multiple backups.
I downloaded latest Client and it doesn't work with the wallets, I've gone back to an earlier client and it works ok.
I assume there have been changes over the past year or so.

I don't have time to figure this all out and try out which Older client works with which backup wallet so I can send my few BTCs to a Brainwallet address and dump the old wallets.

Can I assume that because they are in wallets with backups, encrypted etc that the coins are safe and I just need to go through the trouble of recovering them.
I've heard about pywallet and have tried manually dumping the private keys so I can transfer the coins but so far no luck, it's all Greek to me.

Can I assume the coins are safe (providing the wallets are not iredeemably corrupted, and that one day soon, when I have time I should be able to recover them.

Comment: If a new client fails to open your older wallet, that is a bug and you should report it: http://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues

Answer (score 1):

Your coins should be safe.

No need for a brainwallet:

- open the new client and create a new address
- backup this new wallet
- open your old clients and send your coins to that new address

Never delete the old wallets anyway, just in case.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that the OP doesn't know which version each wallet was created with, so "open your old clients" may or may not work, depending on compatibility between versions.